# SQL Statement That Will Get Table Schema And Created Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sqldatetime

I am trying to create a SQL Statement that will return the table schema name and the if the data was created a day ago.

This will create the SQL Statement  with the table schema name:

```
DECLARE @SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SqlStatement = 
    COALESCE(@SqlStatement, '') + 'DROP TABLE [TMP].' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ';' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TMP'

PRINT @SqlStatement
```

How do I add in the where clause if the table was created a day ago all in the same statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create_date` field is stored in `sys.tables`.  You can then join back to `sys.schemas` to get the schema name.

Something like this:

```
declare @SqlStatement varchar(max)
select @SqlStatement = COALESCE(@SqlStatement, '') + 'DROP TABLE [TMP].' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';' + CHAR(13)
from sys.tables t 
    join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
where s.name = 'TMP'
    and t.create_date > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
print @SqlStatement
```

Comment: It shows the tables that where created today. Show the '>' be changed to '<'

Comment: @nate -- I wasn't completely positive from your question which direction.  The key is you now have access to the `create_date` field and can query accordingly.

Comment: I wanted to query the table name schema that was created a day ago or later. So I could drop all tables that were not created today

Comment: @nate -- Sounds like you're looking for `<` then.  You may need something like `cast(t.create_date as date) < cast(getdate() as date)`